# differences between Use and DB.sp_execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have realized that there are 2 ways of running a dynamic string on a different database:

the first one is the following:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select 1'
exec MyDatabase.sp_execute @sql
```

the second one would be:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Use MyDatabase
            select 1'
exec sp_execute @sql
```

Can anyone point the differences between the 2 approaches? If one is better than the other and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Use` set's the database context for the current session, while in your `exec` statement, you're telling it what database to use for only the statement. After the `exec` statement, your session's database context won't have change to what you ran.

So, in the case of your example, there's no functional difference. In the more general sense, there is a rather large one.

You can also do this:

```
select * from MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
```

That will pull data from another database than your context. You can use this to join data between databases, as well, just like you do normal joins.